# AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.gis.db.models' has no attribute 'JSONField'

Tags: python, django

I'm using a Postgis database for my Django Project which has a field of JSONField in its database. When I run it, I get this error

> AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.gis.db.models' has no attribute 'JSONField'

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share your models.py ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import JSONField
class Question(models.Model):
     text = JSONField(max_length=200)
```

This will solve your error

Comment: It's not working, still i gets the error